# How can we check if two rows/columns in MS-Excel contain same text, irrespective of the case?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

I want to compare two rows or columns in MS-Excel 2013, to check if they have the same text.

It somewhat like the EXACT() function but without being case sensitive.

Like

A1: Abcd

B1: abcd

C1: True (result of matching)

Then the corresponding result should be true. I tried using EXACT() method, but it only returns true if I have exactly the same text (Abcd) in B1.

Comment: Type formula in `C1 = A1=B1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use any of below option

`=A1=B1` or `=EXACT(UPPER(A2),UPPER(B2))`

[image]